# Starting hadoop daemons without password

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I setup single node hadoop cluster in ubuntu by following this pdf:
{http://www.edureka.co/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/15-minute-guide-to-install-Hadoop-Cluster.pdf}. I am able to setup hadoop and its working fine. But whenever I start any hadoop daemons, it asks me my account password. Is it possible to start daemons without prompting the password?
If yes then please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up password less login

1. Run ssh-keygen and take defaults for all prompts
2. cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
3. Make sure permissions on .ssh is drwx------ and on .ssh/id_rsa is -rwx------

Answer (score 0):

1. check ssh configurations
2. copy ssh id's to other nodes
3. make ssh connection like ssh@192.168.10.11